# convert a text file to a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a `tab` separated file with 7 columns. I want to put every column in a separate list in python. After that I would have a list containing 7 python lists .
I tried this but it put each line in a separate list:

```
infile = open('text.txt', 'r')
s = []
for line in infile:
    s.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
```

do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If it is a proper tsv, use the `csv` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
infile = open('text.txt', 'r')
s = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
for line in infile:
    t = line.strip().split('\t')
    for i, p in enumerate(t):
        s[i].append(p)

print(s)
```

Considering file contains:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
```

output:

```
[['1', '8'], ['2', '9'], ['3', '10'], ['4', '11'], ['5', '12'], ['6 ', '13'], ['7', '14']]
```